# Getting Azure VM event logs into Eventhubs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-eventhub

We are currently investigating methods in getting our Security log data out of our Azure VM's and into our SIEM for analysis.

Currently I have been able to get the logs from the VM to log analytics work-space but I'm no sure how to get them from the log analytics workspace to the eventhub to then pull down the events.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge before / how did you overcome this challenge?

I'm currently pull the data into a Log analytics workspace

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

**Azure diagnostic logs** can be streamed in near real time to any application using the built-in “Export to Event Hubs” option in the Portal, or by enabling the Event Hub Authorization Rule ID in a diagnostic setting via the Azure PowerShell Cmdlets or Azure CLI.

**What you can do with diagnostics logs and Event Hubs:**

Here are just a few ways you might use the streaming capability for Diagnostic Logs:

- **Stream logs to 3rd party logging and telemetry systems** – You can stream all of your diagnostic logs to a single event hub to pipe log data to a third-party SIEM or log analytics tool.
- **View service health by streaming “hot path” data to Power BI** – Using Event Hubs, Stream Analytics, and Power BI, you can easily transform your diagnostics data in to near real-time insights on your Azure services.
- **Build a custom telemetry and logging platform** – If you already have a custom-built telemetry platform or are just thinking about building one, the highly scalable publish-subscribe nature of Event Hubs allows you to flexibly ingest diagnostic logs.

After data is displayed in the event hub, you can access and read the data in two ways:

Configure a supported SIEM tool. To read data from the event hub, most tools require the event hub connection string and certain permissions to your Azure subscription. Third-party tools with Azure Monitor integration included.

For more details, refer "[Stream Azure Diagnostic Logs to an event hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-logs-stream-event-hubs)" and "[How to integrate Azure Monitor with SIEM tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs#what-can-i-do-with-the-monitoring-data-being-sent-to-my-event-hub)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: @CheekatalaPradeep-MSFT When I tried to setup diagnostics logs to EventHub via Portal, I was not able to find that option. I could see Azure Monitor, Azure App Insights and Storage Accounts as sinks but not EventHubs to stream the diag logs. Was that something Microsoft removed as I could see other tutorials where people mention there is option to use EventHubs as sink?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t pull the VM data from log analytics to an event hub, you can use windows/Linux diagnostic extensions to route data to an event hub.

[Stream Azure monitoring data to an event hub for consumption by an external tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs)